# Paypal Sandbox integration in asp.net website by using Website Payments Standard

Tags: asp.net, paypal

I have integrated paypal sandbox in my asp.net using Website Payments Standard as follow.

```
<form name="paypal" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="business" value="abc_131556943_biz@gmail.com" />

                            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="MyItem" />

                            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0.01" />

                            <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://stackoverflow.com" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://stackoverflow.com" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
                            <input type="submit" value="Please Wait....." style="visibility: hidden" />
                            </form>
```

Now issue is that when i am redirected to paypal then first it asks to login into paypal sandbox account. I want to ask that is it necessary to login into paypal sandbox for making the payment. Is there any parameter whcih we can send in hidden field so that it does not ask for sandbox login.

Thanks, Rajbir

Answer (score 1):

I usually pre-authenticate into the Sandbox to skip/keep a normal code flow when testing.  I don't know of anything that can be done to by pass it other than using a real account.